# CSV splitting lines of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a Dataframe looking like this that I created using `pandas`:

```
    Line         Article       Quantity         Substance      Score
0  line1         article1          5            substance1     5
1  line2         article2          7            substance2     7
2  line3         article3          7            substance3     10
3  line4         article4          4            substance4     1
4  line5         article6          2            substance5     5
...
```

Then I use `mycsv.to_csv(mypath, sep='|', encoding='utf-8')` to create the csv.

The issue is with the new CSV created looking like this:

```
|Line|Article|Quantity|Substance|Score
0|"line1
"|article1|5|substance1|5
1|"line2
"|article2|7|substance2|7
```

I don't know why it goes to a  new line after `Line` and from where these `"` come from.
I just want my CSV to look like my Dataframe.
A correct display is important for me because this csv is manually reviewed afterwards.
If there is a \n somewhere is there a way to ignore them when I create/display my CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your **Line** column has line break in the end (like \n or \r). Check this out

If it has, just remove it from the DataFrame:

```
df = df.replace('\n','', regex=True)
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore \n?

Comment: @marou95thebest yeah, just remove it from DataFrame: df = df.replace('\n','', regex=True)